# Android ListView Color Change

Tags: android, listview, if-statement

I am developing an app which needs to notify the users how many times a player has played a match.
I'm using a ListView containing the player names.
If a player is selected once, it turns green.
If a player is selected twice it turns yellow, and so on.
The first click works fine, it changes to green.
However, when I click it a second time, nothing happens.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Thanks!

This is the code I am using:

```
if (pos == 1){
                text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                if(numberOfClicks ==2){
                    text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                }else if(numberOfClicks == 3){
                    text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
```

Comment: where you change `numberOfClicks` values in your code?

Comment: are you incrementing the `numberOfClicks` value accordingly? this should be done within the `onClick()`.

Comment: You need to take more precise thing instead of number of clicks to change the background of text

Comment: How did I forget to increment the number of clicks! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making some mistake, your code is not dynamic, if you use condition like `if(pos == 1)` then it will just change text of first list value not other's, so basically when you add more content it will be harder, so use loop and find the position of value and then change the color of list item.

Second thing to do this what you are trying you need to change `numberOfClicks` every time to some variable and every time you need to check that how many times button is clicked, so best way is to use flag integer variable which increment value everytime when you click and then count the number of click and change color.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried to use a loop at first however, it didn't work the way I wanted it to. If I clicked one name it would turn green but if I clicked any other name it would turn yellow rather than turning green first. 
However, this is still happening when I'm stating the positions. Would you have any other suggestion on how to go about this please? Or maybe an example of the way I should do the loop? I may have been doing it wrong! Thanks.

Comment: Then simple `text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);` put this line inside onCreate instead of putting in a onItemClick and rest is same. Try this one.

Comment: I'm using this code in the onItemClickListener : 
OnItemLongClickListener longListen = new OnItemLongClickListener(){
  
 @Override
 public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
        int pos, long id){

To populate my ListView I'm using this method:
 
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to, 0);
 
setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Putting text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); inside onCreate didn't work either. Thanks so much for your help though!